# ajax promise gets overidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

first i call getLiveData which gets data from the server
then some parts of ui are rendered and these parts calls bindLiveData with Id

sometimes data comes later then some parts of UI thats why i wait till request is done.
The problem gots tricky when there is an exception, since the method is called itself again (in realilty up to couple of times)

I will not have calls from UI again , since they call bindLiveData once after render
so In fail method i could grab all Ids and on next successfull ajax reqest i could assinged data.

But what happens then with my infoDataPromise ?? since it will be overidden on error

Does all 'fails' of the previous reqest will fire ? How to avoid this promise gets overriden?

```
  var infoDataPromise;
    var mydata;
    
function getLiveData() {


    infoDataPromise = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "someUrl",
        success: function (data) {mydata = data; },
        error: function () {
            getLiveData();
        }
    });
}

function bindLiveData(Id) {
    infoDataPromise.done(() => {
        if (mydata) {
            var item = mydata.find(x => x.Id === Id);
            adjustUIForId(item);
        }
    }).fail(() => {
        mydata = null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't write functions that manipulate globals.
- Return promises from functions instead
- Use `async/await` syntax to make promises easier to manage
- Use recursion to handle your retry attempts

```js
const getLiveData = async () => {
    const config = {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "someUrl"
    };

    try {
        return await $.ajax(config);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return getLiveData();
    }
}

const handleData = async () => {
    const data = await getLiveData();
    if (!data) return;
    const item = data.find(x => x.Id === Id);
    adjustUIForId(item);
};

handleData();
```

Now `getLiveData` returns a single promise that resolves when there is a successful request and you don't need to worry about any other promises. There's no overwriting going on.

Comment: can't use async/await to old js. and my handleData is called 250 times per some ui parts , your solution will make 250 request.... i think you missunderstoodme

Comment: You can call `getLiveData` once and then pass the single promise it returns to however many functions you want. You can also rewrite `getLiveData` to use `then` and `catch` methods, it will just be harder to read.